# Using Web.Config Active Directory Connection String

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I have a connection string (which works fine) to connect to AD through my web application in my web.config. Traditionally, however, I've created a new connection to pull info. from the user after login like so:

```
Using adDirectory as New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=myou,DC=mydc,DC=dc,DC=com")
Dim adTicketID as String = ticket.Name
myVar = "adDirectory.Children.Find("CN=" & adTicketID).Properties("myproperty").Value
End Using
```

It seems that I should instead use the connection from the web.config like so:

```
Using ADCS as New DirectoryEntry
Dim adTicketID as String = ticket.Name
myVar = "adDirectory.Children.Find("CN=" & adTicketID).Properties("myproperty").Value
End Using
```

Is this possible? How would I accomplish it so that I don't need to constantly create new directoryentries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add various reusable data to your web.config inside of your [appSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx) section.

Web Config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DomainLdapQueryString" value="LDAP://OU=myou,DC=mydc,DC=dc,DC=com"/>
  </appSettings>
```

In your Code

```
Dim Config As Configuration.ConfigurationSettings
Dim LDAPQueryString As String = Config.AppSettings("DomainLdapQueryString")
```